# How to sign up to VEVO without using Facebook

Tags: vevo

When using VEVO it seems impossible to register without using Facebook. No other options are given (even with Incognito)

[image: Forces you to sign up with Facebook]

Is there a path to a regular form registration? I just want to save a playlist.

[image: Playlist option]

Comment: [Well that's no good...](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11965/should-we-restrict-signup-for-a-service-to-facebook-accounts-only)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible now (2016) by going to http://www.vevo.com/signup.

[image]

<del>You can't do that anymore.</del>

> <del>We heard that music video site Vevo was planning a major site redesign, and those news changes are rolling out today just as planned. The first major difference you'll notice is that the only way to sign up for an account is with Facebook, and existing users must now log in with Facebook as well.</del>

<del>[Source](http://www.theverge.com/2012/3/9/2857212/vevo-facebook-integration-itunes-syncing).</del>